# VBA проверка пароля при включенном Charstring

Tags: vba, visual-basic

Проверяю введённые данные при помощи строки

```
If TextBox1.Text = "login" And TextBox2.Text = "password" Then .....
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при включении Charstring * у TextBox2 - перестаёт работать этот фрагмент кода. Как я понимаю - он видит просто звездочки, как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

*TextBox* имеет свойство (*Properties*) `PasswordChar` Записать там символ, которым будут заменяться все водимые символы. Это только визуальное отображение, на само значение не влияет.

Проверка

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     MsgBox TextBox2.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Я это и сделал, но теперь код не определяет вводимый пароль, он пишет, что я неверно ввёл пароль

Comment: Проверьте (код в ответе). Проблема в другом. `PasswordChar` - только видимое отображение, на само значение не влияет.

Comment: msgbox выдал знаки вопроса, вместо введенного пароля

Comment: Что-то где-то как-то... Как будто  это не в *Excel*,  *TextBox* из ближайшего подвала  и система от  китайских производителей... А если написать "Вася" - что в *msgbox*? Откудя взято это - *Charstring*? Похоже, мало Вы рассказали...

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, что значит ваше *«при включении Charstring * у TextBox2»*, но не нужно делать нечего другого кроме того, что до свойства *PasswordChar* написать звёздочку (`*`) или какой-то другой символ.

И всё будет работать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]